# Cannot access thumbdrive via router when GUFW firewall is on

Tags: networking, samba, firewall

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3 32 bit (I mistakenly said it was 16.04.1).

I have wifi via a netgear router.  Connected to the router's USB port is a thumb drive.

When the firewall is turned on (I have not defined any rules yet as I am new to Linux) I do not have access to the thumb drive.  When I turn off the firewall, I have access to the thumb drive.

Specifically, when the firewall is on, when I click on **Browse Network**, I see **Windows Network**.  When I double click on this, nothing happens.

When I turn off the firewall, I double click **Browse Network** and get **Workgroup**.  Double clicking this I get **ReadyShare** (which is a NetGear thing).  When I double click on this I get `USB_Storage`.  Double clicking this I get the `Transfers` folder where my files are.

I tried several of the preconfigured rules (including the preconfigured Samba), and of course, nothing worked.

How can I access the drive with the firewall turned on?

Comment: What ? Can you connect with your firewall disabled? What are you trying g to co next to ? And I can not tell from what you posted where is the usb and if on Windows the windows conig. If it is a firewall problem we need your firewall rules

Comment: There's no such thing as "the latest ubuntu mate 16.04.1".  The latest Ubuntu Mate is 17.10. Good old 16.04 is up to 16.04.3.  So you have a second, unrelated problem there....

Comment: If it's on a 'windows' network, then you probably need to allow samba through your firewall.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo iptables -L`?   Please [edit]  this information into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but the firewall was on when command was issued...

Comment: Please re-enable samba in uwf, then execute the command `sudo ufw status` and append the output of that command to your question.

Comment: Help, what is "uwf"?  Are you referring to the "Firewall Configuration " app?

Comment: In reply to Charles Green "
 
If it's on a 'windows' network, then you probably need to allow samba through your firewall. ", in firewall config app, I selected under rules/preconfigured/application /Samba.  There were 2 Sambas to choose from, but they looked the same to me.

Comment: for Charles Green,root@LapDog:/home/john# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
137,138/udp                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
139,445/tcp                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
137,138/udp (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
139,445/tcp (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Answer (score 0):

Until you can get samba transfers working, you can access the USB via your browser:

Open your browser, and enter the address `192.168.0.1/shares` , assuming that your router addresses have not been changed from the defaults.